# Does casting down to an interface result in losing the derived functionality?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I am attempting to cast down a variable. Essentially I am storing a derived class in an interface variable.

This is causing a compile time error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Auth.Account' to 'IAccount'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So I have cast the variable down to the interface. If I cast it down to its interface am I going to lose any of the derived classes functionality?

```
public interface IAccount
{

}

public class Account :  Xamarin.Auth.Account, IAccount
{

}

...Inside view model
private IAccount _account;
_account = eventArgs.Account; // causes compiler error

_account = (IAccount)eventArgs.Account; // solution but will I loose functionality?

// eventArgs.Account = Xamarin.Auth.Account data type
```

Comment: A cast cannot "lose functionality"; there is no way to change which class an object is.  It might fail, but it won't change anything.

Comment: Do you even need to cast the variable to the interface in the first place? When you cast to an interface, only methods on that interface are available, but your IDE / compiler will show you which methods / properties are available. You won't be able to make a call that passes compilation but throws an error at runtime.

Comment: What will happen if the method declared on the interface and implemented on the class, has references to variables or methods declared on the class.. will all the references will be available after casting the class to the interface?

Answer (score 4):

A cast cannot "lose functionality"; there is no way to change which class an object is.  It might fail, but it won't change anything.

However, downward conversions are permitted implicitly, for this reason; you won't actually get that error.

It sounds like `eventArgs.Account` is actually a `Xamarin.Auth.Account`, which does not implement your interface; therefore, your conversion will fail (unless you happen to know that it really is an instance of your `Account` class at runtime).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Are you saying this cast will fail at runtime because of multiple inheritence? I've successfully compiled this but not run it yet. If it will, any advice on how I can get this to work

Comment: @JakeM what do you mean by multiple inheritance? C# does not support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of the object in the eventArgs is it YourNamespace.Account or Xamarin.Auth.Account ?

I'm betting it's Xamarin.Auth.Account which doesn't inherit IAccount and therefore cannot be cast to it.  I'd suggest turning your Account class into a proxy (wrapper) class which takes a Xamarin.Auth.Account class in its constructor.

```
public interface IAccount
{

}

public class Account :  Xamarin.Auth.Account, IAccount
{
    public Account(Xamarin.Auth.Account account) :
        base(account.Username, account.Properties, account.Cookies)
    {
    }
}

_account = new YourNamespace.Account(eventArgs.Account);
```

Another alternative, perhaps rather than inheriting Xamarin.Auth.Account you could implement the methods in your Account class as [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb383977.aspx) on the Xamarin.Auth.Account class